# Setting text just beneath another text

Tags: html, css

I want the paragraph lie just beneath my navbar brand.

```html
<nav class="navbar bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand"href="index.html">Shop online</a>
    <p>Shop from home</p>
</nav>
```

I applied following css but it not going well

```css
nav p {
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    top: 3.5vh;
    right: 182vh;
    margin-top: 1vh;
}
```

Comment: Hi are you using bootstrap

Comment: Answer depended on it

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```css
nav p{
 font-size:.9em;
 color: #111;
 position: absolute;
 top:60px;
 left:15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand"href="index.html">Shop online</a>
    <p class="d-block float-left">Shop from home</p>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi are you using bootstrap , Answer depended on it. I have try with bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

just add `display: block` to your p

or

add bootstrap `d-block` class

```
<nav class="navbar bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Shop online</a>
    <p class="d-block">Shop from home</p>
</nav>
```

Doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: add d-block class

Answer (score 0):

Place your paragraph tag below the `nav` tag. Like this:

```
<nav class="navbar bg-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand"href="index.html">Shop online</a>
</nav>
<p>Shop from home</p>
```

Now it will be displayed below the navbar.

Comment: i want it below my navbar-brand ,not below the navbar.